# How do I get actual solutions from MaxValue?

Tags: simplifying-expressions, symbolic, maximum

Say I want to calculate the maximum value of a simple function of two variables:

```
f[r_, t_]:= r Cos[t]^3 (1 + r Sin[t])
```

with respect to the variable `t`. For a specific value of `r` there is no problem. Executing

```
MaxValue[{f[.1, t], 0 <= t <= 2 Pi[]}, t]
```

immediately returns `0.00100166`. My problem arises when I want an arbitrary positive real value for `r`, so as to get a function of one variable. I tried a couple of variations of

```
Assuming[r > 0, 
 Evaluate@MaxValue[{Num[r, t], 0 <= t <= 2 Pi[]}, t]
]
```

but all I get in return is the comically unhelpful

```
MaxValue[{r Cos[t]^3 (1 + r Sin[t]) , 0 <= t <= 2 Pi[]}, t]
```

I know I can code a simple algorithm that finds the 0s of the derivatives and then looks at the various values to find the biggest. But this is an expensive symbolic manipulation software, I don't think it's too much to ask that some function can do this.

Comment: Observe that MaxValue[f[r, t], {r, t}] returns infinite if r can take on any positive value.

Comment: I think if you compare `Solve[D[r Cos[t]^3 (1 + r Sin[t]), t] == 0, t]` and `Solve[D[r Cos[t]^3 (1 + r Sin[t]), t] == 0 && 0 <= t <= 2 \[Pi], t]` and ponder the dependence of the solution set on `r`, it might become clearer why `Maximize` has trouble solving the problem generically.

Comment: It is the situation when you have to help Mathematica.